Trying to poll the JFROG artifactory using Jenkins
I need to trigger a Jenkins build when there is change in my artifactory, I will be pushing some artifacts from a development pack, so whenever these is a change in the artifactory location it should trigger my test job
Scenario:
Path: https://artifactory.com/artifactory/adbl-bms-sw-testops/Common/reftestopsint/Regular_Build/1.2.0/
So in this path there will multiple build folder and inside that artifacts will be there, so I need to trigger my test job whenever there is a devpack added, and need to know what made that change
The methods I tried

URL trigger Plugin - I am able to trigger the job according to the changes, but I am not able to find out what made that change
Enable Artifactory trigger - I am using and org level artifactory, not able get any output from this

